# Coroutine is not being called

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

Good day,

I'm new to coding so bear with me. I have a coroutine which I want to call so I have a delay to my respawn. however, it's doing everything but the delay. Unity C# :)

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            StartCoroutine(Reset());
           
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Reset()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
    }
}
```

Comment: set a log message on `IEnumerator` and see if it will be logged or not, I don't think It will but check it,

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Almost the exact same code: An "OnCollisionEnter()" method where I'm trying to Destroy a GameObject and then starting a Coroutine that calls another method. The Coroutine waits 4 seconds then calls another method.

The GameObject I'm trying to destroy HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH the coroutine. My game actually works if I change it from a coroutine that waits 4 seconds and calls the method, to just immediately calling the method.

So it's due to some interaction between a coroutine and destroying a GameObject, even if that GO has nothing to do w/ the coroutine. ARGH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mohamed pointed out, executing gameobject is destroyed before WaitForSeconds properly triggered at the end of the frame, and therefore your code does not reach LevelManager.instance.Respawn(). Would it disturb rest of your flow if destroy is executed after Respawn() like this?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Reset());
    }
}

IEnumerator Reset()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
    LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}

Comment: well it works the game object dos not disappear so i guess ill have to run a console log to see if the collider is destroying but it is resetting me when i grab the collectible so thanks :D

Comment: Yes, it worked. But here, the object is not disappearing, it is there for 2 seconds, I wanted it to disappear.

Comment: @Ashay Raut Try using DestroyImmediate instead of Destroy

Answer (score 3):

it's very simple, the object is already destroyed so what(Script) after `Destroy(gameObject);` on the next frame
will not work, as I told you in the comments the set a log message on `IEnumerator` to check it out.
to understand how it works: Check this Script

```c#
void Awake() // the First Call // all lines inside Awake is Called
{
    Destroy(gameObject); // Object is now Destroyed
    print(1); // on the Same Frame Call // Printed 
    StartCoroutine(Reset()); // Called
}

IEnumerator Reset()
{
    print(2); // will printed ... Called and on the same frame
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); // Called but will be destroyed in the next frame
    print(3); // not printed ..
}

private void Start() // Start will be called after the Awake calls are finished and the object still exists and is active so it will not be Called
{
    print(4); // not printed ..
}
```

Comment: I was so free to fix your code ;) Note btw that `Start` is actually not called in the next frame but rather immediately once all scene's Awake calls are finished and the object still exists and is active and enabled ;)

Comment: good to know, thanks for the editing, I will edit the code comments as well

Comment: @JulianBridges Glad I could help.